# Test button wont print out text

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to get a HTML button to print out text in PHP  and HTML, however nothing appears to happen other than the page refreshing.

```
<?php 
  if ($_POST["submit_button"]) :
    echo "testing";
    ?>
      <p>"testing"</p>
    <?php 
  endif;
?>


<html>
  <body>
    <h3>PHP button test form</h3>
    <form name="test_form" action= "" method="post">
      <button type="submit" name ="submit_button" >Update</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `if($_POST["submit_button"])`, the button holds no value. So this expression will evaluate to false, even if the item exists.

You should check if such item exists, using `isset`.

This should work properly:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"]))
```